# How many sublattices are contained in the powerset lattice of a finite set?

Tags: co.combinatorics, ct.category-theory, universal-algebra

How many sublattices does the powerset lattice $2^n$ contain for $n$ finite? (up to equality, not isomorphism)

I thought for sure this would be easy to find on OEIS, but so far I am coming up empty.

I really am interested in seeing a list of small examples, say up to $n=5$ or $6$ maybe, although perhaps already things blow up too much at that point for this to be feasible. Ideally there would be a systematic way to write down examples, but just as an entryway to the literature, I thought I'd ask this as a counting question.

Comment: The number of Boolean subalgebras of the Boolean algebra would be easier to compute, I guess.

Comment: If $L$ is a sublattice of $P(X)$, then $L$ has a least element $A_{L}$ and greatest element $B_{L}$, and $\mathcal{T}_{L}=\{R\setminus A_{L}\mid R\in L\}$ is a topology on $B_{L}\setminus A_{L}$. Furthermore, every triple $(A,B,\mathcal{T})$ where $A\subseteq B$ and $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology on $B\setminus A$ can be formed this way. Since the specialization ordering gives a correspondence between the topologies and the finite pre-orders, we can count the number of sublattices of $P(X)$ when $X$ is finite in terms of the number of pre-orders.

Comment: @JosephVanName Thanks! As explained in my comment on Keith Kearnes' answer below, I think it's actually the finite topologies themselves that I'm interested -- thanks for explaining the connection! And the fact that one can then reduce further to thinking about the specialization order is exactly the sort of insight I was hoping for!

Comment: A reference is *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 1, second ed., Exercise 3.46.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[OEIS A306445:](https://oeis.org/A306445) 2, 4, 13, 74, 732, 12085, 319988, 13170652, 822378267, 76359798228, 10367879036456, 2029160621690295, 565446501943834078, 221972785233309046708, 121632215040070175606989, 92294021880898055590522262, 96307116899378725213365550192, 137362837456925278519331211455157, 266379254536998812281897840071155592

Number of collections of subsets of $\{1, 2,\ldots,n\}$ that are closed under union and intersection (starting at $n=0$).

This count includes the empty sublattice, so if you don't want that you should subtract one from every term.

Comment: Great, thanks! I neglected to clarify that for me, "sublattice" includes the condition that the bottom and top elements agree with those in the ambient lattice. So what I failed to notice is that I was asking about precisely the number of topologies on a finite set, as mentioned by Joseph van Name and linked to from the OEIS page you found. (BTW this OEIS link doesn't really have _any_ references, but it does link to the OEIS page for finite topologies, which _does_ have ample references it seems.)

Comment: @markvs The formula writes these numbers in terms of the number of finite topologies, but the number of finite topologies does not itself have a formula so far as I understand. So it's more a relationship between two series than a "closed form" formula _per se_.